# Is there a way to close the result list when using keyboard TAB?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state **isSearchActive** that will decide if the ResultList shows or not. I only want to close the ResultList when I TAB outside the form

```
<form
  ref={innerRef} 
>
 <input/>
 <ResultList></ResultList>
 <button/>

</form>
```

I have tried to use the logic for a handleClickOutside function but that fires too fast so when I tab out I get the form as my target and the state won't trigger

```
 if (innerRef?.current?.contains(e.target)) return
 setIsSearchActive(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the focusout event on the form element instead of the click event. This event will fire when the focus moves out of the form element, regardless of whether it moves to another focusable element within the form or outside of it.

You can add an event listener for the focusout event on the form element and update the state accordingly.

```
useEffect(() => {
  innerRef.current.addEventListener('focusout', handleFocusOut);
  return () => {
    innerRef.current.removeEventListener('focusout', handleFocusOut);
  };
}, [innerRef]);

const handleFocusOut = (e) => {
  setIsSearchActive(false);
}
```

This way, whenever the focus moves out of the form element, the handleFocusOut function will be called and setIsSearchActive will be set to false.